# ! Missing } inserted. <inserted text> } l.84 \end {align}

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I am trying to code an equation into LaTeX but I keep getting this error.
I found some similar questions, but the solutions given are also not working.

I'm working in a documentclass `report`. I also tried the code in `article` and `book`. I'm also using the package `amsmath`.

```
\begin{align}
\label{eqn:1}
$\Pi_W$  =  \large{$\frac {(c\rho)^c}{1 - \rho}$}\\
 \notag & = \large{$\frac {(c\rho)^c}{c!} \bigg( {(1-\rho)} \sum_{n=0}^{c-1} \frac {(c\rho)^n}{n!} + \frac {(c\rho)^c}{c!}$ \bigg) ^{-1}}
\end{align}
```

This is the equation I'm trying to get, beginning the second part.
Also I only want the second line to have an equation number.
[image]

Note: I'm very new with LaTeX.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @TobiBS Thank You for the tip. I'll keep that in mind next tuime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with that. In the first place, what are those `$` signs doing there? In the second place, you cannot use `\large` in math mode.

This will compile without errors:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{eqn:1}
\Pi_W  &=  \frac {(c\rho)^c}{1 - \rho}\\
 \notag & = \frac {(c\rho)^c}{c!} \bigg( {(1-\rho)} \sum_{n=0}^{c-1} \frac {(c\rho)^n}{n!} + \frac {(c\rho)^c}{c!} \bigg) ^{-1}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The next time, I suggest that you post a minimal working example.

Comment: I use `\large` because the equation was very small in my pdf document. The & I left there by accident, while copying and pasting.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: May I suggest to use the pair `\biggl( … \biggr)`?